# Print PDF | Javascript won't get the data

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, moodle

In `Moodle` I am using a `javascript` to print the page with `course` `information` in `PDF` (Using in separate file the `TCPDF` `library`)

The javascript:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
$('#page-enrol-index .printpdf').click(function(){
        //jquery extend function
        $.extend(
        {
            redirectPost: function(location, args)
            {
                var form = '';
                $.each( args, function( key, value ) {
                    form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">';
                });
                $('<form action="'+location+'" method="POST">'+form+'</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
            }
        });

        //fill the variables
        var title = $("div.sessioninfo_title span.sessioninfodata").text();
        var description = $("div.content div.summary").text();
        console.log(title);


        //create the pdf
        $.redirectPost("/moodle/local/printpdf.php", {
            ptitle: title, 
            pdesc: description, 
        });
    });
});
```

And the `PDF` (with the two `variables` `$title` and `$description`, which won't print):

```
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
$pdf->AddPage();

if (!empty($_POST["ptitle"])) {
    $title = $_POST["ptitle"];
    $description = $_POST["pdesc"];
}

$html = '<html>
<body>
<img src="/moodle/theme/base/pix/logo.png" alt="test alt attribute" border="0" height="100" width="220" allign="left" /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><font color="#C0C0C0">Organisation name<br><b>Department<br></font></span></p>
<h2>Information about the course</h2>
<!-- 
<h3>'. $title . '</h3><br />
'. $description . '<br />
-->
</body>
</html>';



// $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('CourseInfo.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: Are you directly using the TCPDF library? If so, you should switch to using lib/pdflib.php, as that is a wrapper that avoids some problems with using TCPDF directly. Also I note the use of $_POST in your code - inside Moodle you should always use required_param or optional_param instead (probably not the cause of your problem, but you should change the code anyway).

Comment: Looking again at your code - why have you commented out the variables? The '<!--' is a HTML comment, so the everything from there to '-->' will be hidden in the output (I can only assume TCPDF strips out such comments).

Comment: You are right, that was my mistake. The problem here was, that i missed to add the same code in the debug.js file. Now I have only to figure out how to format the text from the variable $description to be the same as on the course page. Is it possible?